# Android Socket Host is unresolved *.onion

Tags: android, sockets, tor

I try to implement socket connection to hidden service into TOR network. I have onion domain hostname of it hidden service. I have Orbot installed on device. I create socket for connect to hidden service using proxy Orbot. I did it this way:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress(
            "localhost", 9050));
    clientSocket = new Socket(proxy);

    InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(HS_DOMEN, HS_PORT);

    if (remoteAddress.isUnresolved())
        Log.i("LOG", "address unresolved!!!");

    Log.i("LOG", "start connect to inet addr");
    clientSocket.connect(remoteAddress, CONNECT_TIMEOUNT);
    Log.i("LOG", "after connect ward");

    if (clientSocket.isConnected()) {
        Log.i("LOG", "socket connected");
    }
```

Socket successful understand proxy setttings, but when I try to connect to hidden service error occurs:

```
11-06 14:34:57.215: W/System.err(32101): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is 
unresolved: *.onion
11-06 14:34:57.215: W/System.err(32101):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:825)
11-06 14:34:57.215: W/System.err(32101):    at ru.dtlbox.example.clientsample.MainActivity.connectSocket(MainActivity.java:79)
11-06 14:34:57.215: W/System.err(32101):    at ru.dtlbox.example.clientsample.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:128)
11-06 14:34:57.215: W/System.err(32101):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Onion host name is valid, because I tried to test it using Orweb, everything works fine. There is nginx server on 80 port. But my Socket can't resolve this onion address. I think it  occurs because InetAddress class can't resolve IP address for passed hostname. But how can I setup right settings mayby or use different way to connect? Is there any idea? Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your question was asked quite awhile ago. I am surprised not even one answer was given. I think that perhaps you might have found a solution by now. However, the following answer then is for those who might seek for a solution to this problem in the future and find this post.

I recently had the same problem trying to connect a client socket to a server socket over tor using an onion address. I spent many hours researching code of open source programs from the Gaurdian Project [link](http://github.com/guardianproject).

It is when I was looking over the now deprecated Orlib library that I noticed a library called jsocks was being used. I found the library at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsocks/, installed it in android studio as a library, and used the Socks5 proxy and SocksSocket to successfully connect. I am not sure yet why it works, but it does.

Here is the connection code, the .onion address is obscured.

```
 private void connect(){
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              System.out.println("Orbot Running: " + OrbotHelper.isOrbotRunning(getApplicationContext()));

              int proxyPort = 9050;
              String proxyHost = "127.0.0.1";
              String remoteHost = "[address].onion";
              int remotePort = 12345;

              try {
                  socks5Proxy = new Socks5Proxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);
                  socks5Proxy.resolveAddrLocally(false);
                  socket = new SocksSocket(socks5Proxy, remoteHost, remotePort);

                  out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                  receive();
              }catch (IOException e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      }).start();
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please try to look at my question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829730/android-orbot-malformed-reply-from-socks-server I have tried implementing your solution but it doesnt work