# Android Orbot malformed reply from SOCKS server

Tags: android, tor, socks

I am trying to enable TOR support on my own XMPP app in android. I am using orbot as TOR proxy and I have the following code to connect app socket:

```
socket = new Socket(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9050)));
socket.connect(addr, Config.SOCKET_TIMEOUT * 1000);
```

but I am getting `Malformed reply from SOCKS server` even that my Orbot is up and running. I believe that this error is thrown when app cant access proxy server or mentioned server is not SOCKS proxy.

I have also tried to use jsocks:

```
Socks5Proxy sProxy = new Socks5Proxy("127.0.0.1", 9050);
sProxy.resolveAddrLocally(false);
String host = account.getServer().toString();
int port = 5222;
System.out.println(host + ":" + port);
try {
    socket = new SocksSocket(sProxy, host, port);
}catch(SocksException sock_ex){
    System.err.println("SocksException:"+sock_ex);
}
System.out.println("here we are");
```

where host is "jabbim.com"
But I never get to "here we are" println so it looks like my app hangs somewhere on creating SocksSocket but I am not getting any errors either. When I debug it it hangs on impl.getInputStream somewhere in jsocks (PlainSocketImpl I believe)

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using

```
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.4"
compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.4"
```

and then connecting using this code:

```
final Random rndForTorCircuits = new Random();
String user = rndForTorCircuits.nextInt(100000) + "";
String pass = rndForTorCircuits.nextInt(100000) + "";
ProxyInfo proxyInfo = new ProxyInfo(ProxyInfo.ProxyType.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050, user, pass);
socket = proxyInfo.getSocketFactory().createSocket(addr.getHostName(), addr.getPort());
```

by using this you get socket that is already connected to proxy.